# Adding support for bq32000

Tags: debian, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, real-time-clock

I have BBB running lastest debian and rtc bq32000 connected to it's I2C bus. ***i2cdetect*** shows presence of the device at valid address(0x68). I've downloaded ***rtc-bq32k.c*** driver and stuck. Can anyone point me out how to proceed further?

Comment: So, what exactly an issue do you have?

Comment: Thanks for response, problem was solved. The issue was lack of linux experience.